# Jquery click function only works after the second click

Tags: jquery

I created an ul dynamically, but when i used click function on the a tag inside the li tag, it only works after the second click. Here is my script

```
var uList;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        uList = $("#room");
        $("#btn").click(function () {
            appendLI();
        });

    });
    function test() {
        if ($("#room li").length > 0) {
            $("li .roomName").on("click", function () {
                alert($(this).text());
            });
        }
    }
    function appendLI() {
        var li = $("<li/>").appendTo(uList);
        var aaa = $("<a/>").prop("class", "roomName").prop("href", "javascript:test();").text("Google 1").appendTo(li);
    }
```

Here is my HTML

```
 <input type="text" autofocus/>
<ul id="room">
</ul>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="SET" />
```

Comment: First: `var li = $("<li/>").appendTo(uList);` You're trying to append to an `undefined` variable (`uList`) instead of an element. Second: using global variable is bad. Thirth: you shall define `appendLI` function before using.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however, the uList is defined at the $(document).ready, why was is undefined? Can you explain why using global variable be considered bad?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The on click event isn't written right right;

```
function test() {
        if ($("#room li").length > 0) {
            $("#room").on("click", '.roomName', function () {
                alert($(this).text());
            });
        }
    }
```

I re-wrote your block of code here for you;

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PWVmjJ

Comment: thank you!! It works, however, may you point out where i was wrong? Why did it work on the 2nd time?

Comment: @KhoaĐỗ Event delegation. You were attaching events to `li .roomName` elements that don't exist yet. This snippet attaches the event to `li`, then checks if the original trigger was `.roomName` on click. This will keep working even if you add `.roomName` to `li` after binding the event listener.

Comment: @godfrzero thanks. Just found the document about event delegation https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/